# Received "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index" in Python

Tags: python, json

I have run the following code on python in order to retrieve various crypto currency closing prices from their inception. I have run it successfully using the following tickers:

```
tickers = ['USDT_BTC','USDT_BCH','USDT_ETC','USDT_XMR','USDT_ETH','USDT_DASH',
 'USDT_XRP','USDT_LTC','USDT_NXT','USDT_STR','USDT_REP','USDT_ZEC']
```

I now have changed it as follows (full code included) and get a ValueError.

[LN1]

```
 def CryptoDataCSV(symbol, frequency):

        #Params: String symbol, int frequency = 300,900,1800,7200,14400,86400

        #Returns: df from first available date

        url ='https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair='+symbol+'&end=9999999999&period='+str(frequency)+'&start=0'

        df = pd.read_json(url)

        df.set_index('date',inplace=True)

        df.to_csv(symbol + '.csv')

        print('Processed: ' + symbol)
```

[LN2]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

[LN3]

```
    tickers = 'ETH_BTC','STR_BTC','XMR_BTC','XRP_BTC','LTC_BTC','DASH_BTC',
'ETC_BTC','POT_BTC','OMG_BTC','FCT_BTC','ZEC_BTC','BTS_BTC','VTC_BTC',
'XEM_BTC','MAID_BTC','DGB_BTC','STRAT_BTC','LSK_BTC','XVC_BTC','SC_BTC',
'DOGE_BTC','XBC_BTC','GNT_BTC','EMC2_BTC','CLAM_BTC','RIC_BTC','SYS_BTC',
'DCR_BTC','STEEM_BTC','ZRX_BTC','GAME_BTC','VIA_BTC','NXC_BTC','NXT_BTC'
,'VRC_BTC','NAV_BTC','PINK_BTC','STORJ_BTC','ARDR_BTC','BCN_BTC','CVC_BTC',
'EXP_BTC','LBC_BTC','GNO_BTC','GAS_BTC','OMNI_BTC','XCP_BTC','NEOS_BTC',
'BURST_BTC','AMP_BTC','FLDC_BTC','FLO_BTC','SBD_BTC','BLK_BTC','BTCD_BTC',
'NOTE_BTC','GRC_BTC','PPC_BTC','BTM_BTC','XPM_BTC','NMC_BTC','PASC_BTC',
'NAUT_BTC','BELA_BTC','SJCX_BTC','HUC_BTC','RADS_BTC']
```

[LN4]

```
for ticker in tickers:
        CryptoDataCSV(ticker, 86400)
```

> I now get the following error:
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 for ticker in tickers:
>   ----> 2     CryptoDataCSV(ticker, 86400)
>
> in CryptoDataCSV(symbol, frequency)
>         7     url ='https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair='+symbol+'&end=9999999999&period='+str(frequency)+'&start=0'
>         8 
>   ----> 9     df = pd.read_json(url)
>        10 
>        11     df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in
>   read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes,
>   convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit,
>   encoding, lines)
>       352         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates,
>       353                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
>   --> 354                           date_unit).parse()
>       355 
>       356     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in parse(self)
>       420 
>       421         else:
>   --> 422             self._parse_no_numpy()
>       423 
>       424         if self.obj is None:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in
>   _parse_no_numpy(self)
>       637         if orient == "columns":
>       638             self.obj = DataFrame(
>   --> 639                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
>       640         elif orient == "split":
>       641             decoded = dict((str(k), v)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in **init**(self,
>   data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
>       273                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
>       274         elif isinstance(data, dict):
>   --> 275             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>       276         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
>       277             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _init_dict(self,
>   data, index, columns, dtype)
>       409             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
>       410 
>   --> 411         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>       412 
>       413     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)    5494     # figure out the index, if necessary    5495     if index is None:
>   -> 5496         index = extract_index(arrays)    5497     else:    5498         index = _ensure_index(index)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   extract_index(data)    5533     5534         if not indexes and not
>   raw_lengths:
>   -> 5535             raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'    5536                              ' an index')    5537
>
> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: I don't know if read_json understands URLs, but when I tried getting results through requests, I got "invalid currency pair".

Comment: @COLDSPEED did it indicate which currency pair is erring? i have run it with the shorter list and it works fine. any suggestions of a rewrite would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped. On trying with your smaller list, I was able to get results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your data, and it appears that some of your currency pairs do not work at all, returning a json of the form:

```
{"error":"Invalid currency pair."}
```

When this is returned, `pd.read_json` throws an error, because it can't convert this to a dataframe.

The simplest workaround is to use a `try-except` brace and handle any non-working tickers.

```
broken_tickers = []

for t in tickers:
    url ='https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair={}&end=9999999999&period={}&start=0'.format(t, 86400)

    try:
        df = pd.read_json(url)
    except ValueError:
        broken_tickers.append(t)
        continue

    df.set_index('date')
    df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(t))
```

I've gotten rid of the function, I didn't really feel it necessary here but you can add it back in.

Comment: i made a total blunder in the currency pairs. BTC should lead. in this way it is 'BTC_ETC'....

Comment: i have another query though, which I have posted as well. your assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: need to create a single csv file from about 70files or so. basically to have all daily prices in one place. unfortunately the time series vary significantly based on when the coins came into existence. the same fields in each file and i only need closing data for each coin in the new file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184493/combining-multiple-csv-files-into-a-single-csv-with-customisation-using-python?noredirect=1#comment81318711_47184493